# I can't link static library with cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, static-linking

I try to link X11, giblib as static library with cmake.

So I append this code in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS '-static')

target_link_libraries(Printmade2 Imlib2)
target_link_libraries(Printmade2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a)
target_link_libraries(Printmade2 /usr/lib/libgiblib.a)
```

After execute 'make', this message appears.

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(OpenDis.o): In function `OutOfMemory':
(.text+0x459): undefined reference to `xcb_disconnect'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(OpenDis.o): In function `XOpenDisplay':
(.text+0x8f5): undefined reference to `xcb_get_setup'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(OpenDis.o): In function `XOpenDisplay':
(.text+0xedb): undefined reference to `xcb_get_maximum_request_length'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(xcb_disp.o): In function `_XConnectXCB':
(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `xcb_parse_display'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(xcb_disp.o): In function `_XConnectXCB':
(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(xcb_disp.o): In function `_XConnectXCB':
(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `xcb_get_file_descriptor'
...
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libX11.a(ClDisplay.o): In function `XCloseDisplay':
(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `xcb_disconnect'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess something is missded, so I should link something more

but I can't find .o file in my file system.

(For example, OpenDis.o, xcb_disp.o, ClDisplay.o)

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the libxcb static libraries. http://xcb.freedesktop.org/

Comment: When I link libxcb library, error message is changed. '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libxcb.a(xcb_auth.o): In function `_xcb_get_auth_info':
(.text+0x68a): undefined reference to `XdmcpWrap'' Maybe libxcb.a needs some other libraries. Is there some ways I can know related library?

Comment: I find every related library. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: As a FYI, a lot of library projects will create something like _/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libname.pc_ That file contains hints for the linker to find stuff. Don't know if the Xorg stuff creates those files or not, but they can come in useful as a hint when you're trying to deduce static linking dependencies